# Handling https requests using a SOCK_STREAM proxy

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, https

I'm working on a project that allows a user to redirect his browsing through a proxy. The system works like this - a user runs this proxy on a remote PC and then also runs the proxy on his laptop. The user then changes his browser settings on the laptop to use localhost:8080 to make use of that local proxy, which in turn forwards all browser traffic to the proxy running on the remote PC.

This is where I ran into HTTPS. I was able to get normal HTTP requests working fine and dandy, but as soon as I clicked on google.com, Firefox skipped my proxy and connected to https://google.com directly.

My idea was to watch for browser requests the say *CONNECT host:443* and then use the python ssl module to wrap that socket. This would give me a secure connection between the outer proxy and the target server. However, when I run wireshark to see how a browser request looks like before ssl kicks in, it's already there, meaning it looks like the browser connects to port 443 directly, which explains why it omitted my local proxy.

I would like to be able to handle to HTTPS as that would make for a complete browsing experience.

I'd really appreciate any tips that could push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after doing a fair amount of reading on proxies, I found out that my understanding of the problem was insufficient.

For anyone else that might end up in the same spot as me, know that there's a pretty big difference between HTTP, HTTPS, and SOCKS proxies.

**HTTP** proxies usually take a quick look into the HTTP headers to determine where to forward the whole packet. These are quite easy to code on your own with some basic knowledge of sockets.

**HTTPS** proxies, on the other hand, have to work differently. They should either be able to do the whole SSL magic for the client or they could try to pass the traffic without changes, however if the latter solution is chosen, the users IP will be known. This is a wee bit more demanding when it comes to coding.

**SOCKS** proxies are a whole different, albeit really cool, beast. They work on the 5th layer of the OSI model and honestly, I have no clue as to where I would even begin creating one. They achieve both security and anonymity. However, I do know that a person may be able to use SSH to start a SOCKS proxy on their machine, just read this http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html . That link also gave an idea that it should be possible to use SSH from a Python script to make it much more convenient.

Hope this helps anyone with the same question as I had. Good luck!